# Find a minimum of a function with constraints (separating hyperplanes)

Tags: optimization

I'm reading "The Elements of Statistical Learning", to be precise chapter about optimal separating hyperplanes (SVM classification problem) and I've stuck with the following.
I have a function to be maximized:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_ia_ky_iy_kx_i^Tx_k,
$$

subject to:

$$
0 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_ia_i, \quad b = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_iy_ix_i, \quad a_i \ge 0 \quad \forall{i}, \quad a_i[y_i(x_i^Tb + b_o) - 1] = 0 \quad \forall{i}
$$

And it's written in the book that it's *"a simpler convex optimization problem, for which standard software can be used"*, but I'm not very familiar with optimization methods used in such software.

Could you please suggest which method should I use to find a solution? Which method is commonly used in SVM implementations?

Comment: I believe you are interested in linearly separable formulations. Because constraints are affine (and the problem is convex) duality gap is 0. Primal-dual solutions we quite popular back then, so "primal-dual"  could be a good starting point. Please also check https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/svm.pdf . Regarding actual numerical algorithms being used in real-life you may find it useful to check Matlab's implementation

Comment: Thank you, good link. As far as I see SVM presentations also ends with the problem described above, and it's still unclear for me which method exactly should I use to find an optimal solution. It seems that this is quadratic programming problem, but again I don't understand how to formulate it in terms of QP.